# Highcharts: Pie Charts Labels Position

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/2xgkzyh4/

Is there any setting to place the labels more properly without adjusting them independently?

Firefox should be more up, Others should be more up and right...

[image]

Code:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    connectorWidth: 12,
                    style : {
                    fontSize: 25
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 45.0],
                ['IE', 26.8],
                ['Safari', 8.5],
                ['Opera', 6.2],
                ['Others', 0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: This is default behaviour of Highcharts. You can [wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) the position method or disable dataLabels and use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to add custom shapes.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found label positioning for pie (as well as polar and spider) charts difficult to manage. Depending on your data and your desired format, they can be very fussy and unruly to position as you'd prefer.

I'd suggest removing the labels altogether and go with a legend instead. I've updated your code snippet with this concept.

Please let me know if this is helpful for you!

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'gray',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            x: 0, y: 50
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: { enabled: false },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 45.0],
                ['IE', 26.8],
                ['Safari', 8.5],
                ['Opera', 6.2],
                ['Others', 0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. Not sure if it will be accepted (it's not my call).

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to reply back to this thread if you need any further input or thoughts on another alternative.